# Changing default font on tint R package

Tags: r, fonts, r-markdown, tint, tufte

I've read the documentation for the "tint" package: 'tint' is not 'Tufte' and I couldn't find a way to change the default font for both the PDF and html outputs. Is there a way to do this from the Markdown document (YAML header)?

Thank you!

Comment: For PDF or HTML output?

Comment: For both outputs. Sorry I didn't specify it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for [tintBook](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tint/blob/da953d81acd884aca923dd90f5d300721bda0e38/inst/rmarkdown/templates/tintBook/resources/tintBook-template.tex#L124), [tintPdf](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tint/blob/da953d81acd884aca923dd90f5d300721bda0e38/inst/rmarkdown/templates/tintPdf/resources/tintPdf-template.tex#L121) and [tintHTML](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tint/blob/da953d81acd884aca923dd90f5d300721bda0e38/inst/rmarkdown/templates/tintHtml/resources/tint.css#L51) I come to the conclusion that there is no direct support. For PDF output (ie `tintBook` and `tintPDF`) you can always use raw LaTeX even though the standard `mainfont` etc. are not supported, e.g.:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
  - \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
```

For a Tufte-Like look. Or

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
```

For using IBM Clear Sans. But for HTML output I know of no simple way to customize this. However, the major point of the `tint` package is a different set of default fonts.

Comment: Thank you! I want to use IBM's "Clear Sans" font, so I wrote:
    header-includes:
     -\usepackage{fontspec}
     -\setmainfont{Clear Sans}

But I get the following error:
    Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
    ! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.
    ! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or
    ! "lualatex"instead of "latex" or "pdflatex".
    ! See the fontspec documentation for further information.

I tried to use: latex_engine: xelatex in the YAML header but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @AlexisSolis iIt seems that `tintPdf` takes an arguemnt `latex_engine` but does not forward it further: https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tint/blob/da953d81acd884aca923dd90f5d300721bda0e38/R/pdf.R#L5-L7 So later on the default `pdflatex` is used. How about using `tufte` instead? Alternativley you can use `- \usepackage{ClearSans}` in the YAML header.